# changing language of jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

hello im new to jquery and since my application is in french I want to change the language of datepicker to match it since not everyone who will use the app knows english

Here is my datepicker with jquery-ui as a simplified version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
   });
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Here is the link to the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r1cpw2sn/
datepicker.setdefaults dosen't seem to work and I didn't find another option appart from putting all month name in an array which dosen't seem like a good idea to me

Any tips on how to make this work would be really appreciated

Comment: Have you included the French language file? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Comment: i didn't know i had to do that ill add it and see if it works

Comment: it works !! so if you write it as an answer ill accept it afterwards

Comment: it's already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865091/jquery-datepicker-language

Comment: oh ok but thanks for the quick help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add specific language file to your project as specified in [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n).

and also refer stack overflows answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865091/jquery-datepicker-language).