# JQuery datepicker language not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, typescript

I using jquery datepickers in my project and need to have local language on it.

[image]

I need to pass language from back end via `gon.locale`(rails stuff)

So here is my ts code

```
 const search_legs_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker");
var leg_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker").datepicker({

  language: gon.locale,
  classes: 'inline-picker',
  altField: '#search_legs_1_date',
  defaultDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
  minDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
  maxDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: (formattedDate, date, inst) => {
    if ($("#search_legs_1_hotel_date").length > 0) {
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
    }
  }
})
```

I checked `gon.locale` with console and get  `sv-SE` so it's pass language.

Also I try to do it like this

```
language:"sv-SE"
```

It not works too.

But for some reasons I have `en` at my datepickers.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Have you looked here https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization?

Comment: Could this be the answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865091/jquery-datepicker-language

Comment: Okay, but where I need to place language file?@SANA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the language file.

> Datepicker provides support for localizing its content to cater for
>   different languages and date formats. Each localization is contained
>   within its own file with the language code appended to the name, e.g.,
>   jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js for French. The desired localization file
>   should be included after the main datepicker code. Each localization
>   file adds its options to the set of available localizations and
>   automatically applies them as defaults for all instances.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Localization files can be found there : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Comment: Where I need to place language file?

Comment: It's written in the quote. The desired localization file should be included after the main datepicker code. Now I guess you have the elements.

Also I don't see a _datepicker-sv-SE.js_ in their github so maybe you should try to get `sv` from your backend and not `sv-SE`. And the file that you would include would be this one https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-sv.js

Comment: Thank's it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include language file and then set the default language as "sv".

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="search_legs_1_datepicker" name="date1"/>



const search_legs_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker");
var leg_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker").datepicker({

  //language: gon.locale,
  classes: 'inline-picker',
  altField: '#search_legs_1_date',
  defaultDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
  minDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
  maxDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: (formattedDate, date, inst) => {
    if ($("#search_legs_1_hotel_date").length > 0) {
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
    }
  }
})


$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['sv']);
```

This file supports all languages - "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"

If you want to include specific file then get the specific langauge file from here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n.