# How to set datepicker language in Symfony 4 templates

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony4

I am trying to get the JQuery datepicker working in the French language (fr), it works but in the default language (English)  ...

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
 {% endblock %}

 {% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr.js"> </script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".js-datepicker").datepicker({
            format : "dd/mm/yyyy",
            language : "fr"
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Any hints ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1865091/351893

Comment: @JochenJung thanks for your comment, but I already tried including the required language definition file, but it didn't work.