# Change DatePicker langage on yadcf

Tags: jquery, datatables, datepicker, yadcf

Currently we're implementing yadcf to filter through the datatable. So far everything works fine but we're facing an issue with the datepicker for filter_type date/range_date.

I would like to change the langage of datepicker from english default to french

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865091/jquery-datepicker-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solve my problem

```
$.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {clearText: 'Effacer', clearStatus: '',
closeText: 'Fermer', closeStatus: 'Fermer sans modifier',
prevText: '<Préc', prevStatus: 'Voir le mois précédent',
nextText: 'Suiv>', nextStatus: 'Voir le mois suivant',
currentText: 'Courant', currentStatus: 'Voir le mois courant',
monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
'Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'],
monthStatus: 'Voir un autre mois', yearStatus: 'Voir un autre année',
weekHeader: 'Sm', weekStatus: '',
dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
dayStatus: 'Utiliser DD comme premier jour de la semaine', dateStatus: 'Choisir le DD, MM d',
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', firstDay: 0, 
initStatus: 'Choisir la date', isRTL: false};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```