# jQuery Datepicker Japanese Calendar

Tags: jquery

I am developing a Japanese Website and it seems an English Calendar is hard for them. How can I change this Calendar to Japanese Text or any local language. I am using PHP

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true
})
```

What else i can add on this jquery code to change the language

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865091/jquery-datepicker-language.
I think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Create your own language object for date picker:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ja']);
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
   language: 'ja'
})
```

update Text with the Japanese language in following code

```
   $.datepicker.regional['ja'] = {
  "closeText": "Done",
  "prevText": "Prev",
  "nextText": "Next",
  "currentText": "Today",
  "monthNames": [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ],
  "monthNamesShort": [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ],
  "dayNames": [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ],
  "dayNamesShort": [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat"
  ],
  "dayNamesMin": [
    "Su",
    "Mo",
    "Tu",
    "We",
    "Th",
    "Fr",
    "Sa"
  ],
  "weekHeader": "Wk",
  "dateFormat": "mm/dd/yy",
  "firstDay": 0,
  "isRTL": false,
  "showMonthAfterYear": false,
  "yearSuffix": ""
};
```