# Japanese Date Picker Calender

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, geolocation

**Original Question**

I have read [jQuery Datepicker Japanese Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891547/jquery-datepicker-japanese-calendar), [jquery japanese datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705156/jquery-japanese-datepicker),
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization and other sources but still cannot get my calender to display the days correctly.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="i18n/datepicker-ja.js"></script>





<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ja" ] );
   
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">

</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Update**

I think there was a weird glitch with my Google Chrome, I had to go into settings and click 'Reset and clean up'. I talk about it more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822680/jquery-date-picker-calender-not-working-in-asian-and-some-european-cities/69871273#69871273).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include built-in support for languages like this :

```js
/* Japanese initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['ja'] = {
        closeText: '閉じる',
        prevText: '&#x3c;前',
        nextText: '次&#x3e;',
        currentText: '今日',
        monthNames: ['1月','2月','3月','4月','5月','6月',
        '7月','8月','9月','10月','11月','12月'],
        monthNamesShort: ['1月','2月','3月','4月','5月','6月',
        '7月','8月','9月','10月','11月','12月'],
        dayNames: ['日曜日','月曜日','火曜日','水曜日','木曜日','金曜日','土曜日'],
        dayNamesShort: ['日','月','火','水','木','金','土'],
        dayNamesMin: ['日','月','火','水','木','金','土'],
        weekHeader: '週',
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        yearSuffix: '年'};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ja']);
});
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ja" ] );
   
  } );
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Other solution, you can use the option to change the region of datepicker :

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["ja"])
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: Could you put your first solution in a JSFiddle? I am struggling to implement it.

Comment: @RossSymonds here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57hoeLz8/)  link, I hope it gonna helps you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "option" to change the region of the datepicker to "ja" and add the following script with your jQuery and jQuery-UI script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a working example:

```js
      $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["ja"])
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: Please see the bottom of my question for updates.

Comment: It seems to be displaying the days correctly both in my snippet, as well as Maestro's identical answer

Comment: There is a problem with the numbers. It is not displaying 1-31. Instead it is displaying 1-18 and duplicating the numbers.