# JQuery date picker calender not working in Asian and some European cities

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I run [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in London, Mountain View, San Fransico and São Paulo the day figures on the calender are correct. When I run the site in Tokyo, Shanghai, Mumbai, Moscow and Berlin the day figures on the calender are wrong.

The other day I faced this problem on my own site. And after rummaging through my code, it started to become clear it wasn't a coding issue. There is another problem at play.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went into settings and did 'Reset and clean up'.

[image]

And I went into Google Chrome Developer Console and changed the Sensors location value to No override.

[image]