# jquery japanese datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Good day SO.

I am still a noob in JS/jQuery so please forgive me for asking something so simple. I want to create a datepicker with a japanese language. However I can't seem to change it to japanese. I have tried/search different SO articles but still no luck.

One [SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1865228/7434025) suggested this [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/main/ui/i18n) source code for datepicker. Maybe my declaration is wrong or something. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rodjames/4nceuakm/2/).

I have tried both `<input type="text" name="fr" class="datepicker" id="fr">` and `<input type="date" name="fr" class="datepicker" id="fr">`

Comment: Is ```datepicker-ja.js``` called ? Do you try ```$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ja']);``` ?

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with jquery itself. I dont think I added it. where and how should I add these ?